# Importing deepspeech error: Module not found

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to install `DeepSearch` library so that I can use the pretrained model to build the Speech to Text Project.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a1bcd52700aa> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import deepspeech
      2 
      3 # Path to the pre-trained model files
      4 model_path = "/content/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm"
      5 scorer_path = "/content/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer"  # Optional, for improved performance

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepspeech'
```

---

I have got the module not found error, and I tried using version also but it gives me the error of couldn't found the suitable version.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech==0.9.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech==0.9.3
```

---

I tried using `deepspeech github` directory when I tried to install the `setupfile` and requirements.txt. I have got the error:

```
 Collecting absl-py==0.9.0
  Downloading absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 104.0/104.0 kB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

---

So how to install the deepspeech library?

Comment: What is your python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest release of deepsearch was 3 years back in December 2020

[image]

You are not able to install deepsearch because it only supports `python <= 3.6`  which is outdated. If you want to use, you can download older version of python separately and install deepsearch.

[image]

**https://pypi.org/project/deepspeech/#description**